# Why did Death Eaters try to stun Harry in the circular hallway, even though he had the prophecy?

Tags: harry-potter, ministry-of-magic

Here is the paragraph from the book:

> "There they are!" she shrieked.
>
> Stunning Spells shot across the room: Harry smashed his way through the door ahead, flung Ron unceremoniously from him and ducked back to help Neville in with Hermione: they were all over the threshold just in time to slam the door against Bellatrix.
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix* (2003)</sub>

**Note:** Later on, it mentions that they were not bewitching Harry, in case they hit the prophecy.

Comment: Are they trying to stun him or the people around him?

Comment: Got no idea about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They were likely trying to use spells that would not hurt the prophecy if it was hit instead of Harry. Thus, there are no Reductors, for example. So why would they worry about "bewitching" Harry? [At least some spells can confused objects](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Confundus_Charm), such as when Barty Crouch Junior Confunded the Goblet of Fire. Casting a spell on a prophecy that might make it start spouting the wrong information would likely be a bad move.